# Render an array of refs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, use-ref

I have to perform the following steps on an array:

- Create an array of refs outside the component
- create a form
- inside the form make a map of the array and render an input for each element
- the input (when in focus) at the press of "enter" puts the next input in focus if there is any, otherwise it submits the form

My code is the following:

```
const array = new Array(5).fill(createRef());


const Step1 = () => {
   
    return (
        <>
            {/*Form  */}
           <form style={{margin:30}} >
                {/*- inside the form make a map of the array and render an input for each element, - the input (when in focus) at the press of "enter" puts the next input in focus if there is any, otherwise it submits the form */}
                {array.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <input
                            key={index}
                            ref={item}
                            type="text"
                            placeholder={`Input ${index + 1}`}
                            onKeyPress={(e) => {
                                if (e.key === "Enter") {
                                    if (array[index + 1]) {
                                        array[index + 1].current.focus();
                                    } else {
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        console.log("submit");
                                    }
                                }
                            }}
                        />
                    );
                })}
                <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
           </form>
        </>
    )
}

export default Step1;
```

The last point doesn't work, how can I change the code to make it work? Solved

The only problem is that I can't write in the inputs. Solved

If I wanted to use an Input component that takes the ref via forwardRef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. The main problem is your use of [`Array#fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) which when used like this fills the array with references to a single object. As such you are ending up with a single `ref` which you succesively assign each input to. The solution is to map the array and return a new `ref` on each iteration.

```
const array = new Array(5).fill(null).map(() => createRef());
// or
const array = Array.from({length: 5}, () => createRef());
```

Your second problem is that `enter` automatically submits the form so you need to `preventDefault()` at the top level of the `if` block.

```js
const { createRef } = React;

const array = Array.from({length: 5}, () => createRef());

const Step1 = () => {

  function focusNextRef(e, index) {
    if (e.key === 'Enter') {
      e.preventDefault(); // <-- move preventDefault()
      if (array[index + 1]) {
        array[index + 1].current.focus();
      } else {
        console.log('submit');
      }
    }     
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form style={{ margin: 30 }} >
        {array.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <input
              key={index}
              ref={item}
              type="text"
              placeholder={'Input ' + (index + 1)}
              onKeyPress={(e) => focusNextRef(e, index)}
            />
          );
        })}
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Step1 />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Edited to fix non-responsive inputs. (`preventDefault()` should be inside the `if` block)